# NPM won't install pug?

Tags: node.js, npm

Can anyone help me decipher what this message is about?
I have another app with pug installed, yet now I cannot create a new module installation for some reason.

I'm installing pug local to the app into node_modules

I'm just trying to get work done, so if I have missed something simple, my stress level has not been helpful with keeping precise vision.

My system is for ongoing development so I don't muck around with upgrades, which historically has broken all kinds of other stuff.

My other app works fine.

```
# npm install --save pug@2.0.0-beta4 <= Because the working app uses this one
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-35-generic-pae
npm ERR! argv "/home/kingram/.nvm/v0.10.46/bin/node" "/home/kingram/.nvm/v0.10.46/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "pug@2.0.0-beta4"
npm ERR! node v0.10.46
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! path /home/kingram/.npm/wordwrap/0.0.2
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/kingram/.npm/wordwrap/0.0.2'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/kingram/.npm/wordwrap/0.0.2']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/kingram/.npm/wordwrap/0.0.2',
npm ERR!   parent: 'cliui' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/kingram/node/fssreg/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install using sudo, ie - `sudo npm install ...`. This will prompt you for your root password.

It looks like root privileges are required to install the package you're looking for. Though this shouldn't really be the case, you can fix this....[check out this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

Comment: I'm not trying to install it globally. That was done already.
I'm installing it locally. That's the source of my confusion.

Comment: who is the owner of the folder and subfolders? Take a look at the link I provided you, it should help in allowing you to install locally.

Comment: The link you sent is about global installs. None of the options change anything for me. I own all the relevant directories, as I am using nvm. So that strategy is null. I am doing a LOCAL install.

Comment: It appears that some of the directories in npm are owned by root.
So you were correct that it was a permission problem. Just not the solution as defined in the link. It's a simple chown fix.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Sorry for the misunderstanding with the link.

Answer (score 1):

After some prodding by @zillaofthegods, it turns out some of directories in ~/.npm were owned by root. In particular the wordwrap module directory.

Changed the permissions and npm installed it fine.

One of those things I would not have caught without some prodding, so thanks.